# gdal_translate or gdalwarp: Preserve noData value when using DISCARD_LSB option

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, 32bit

I want to reduce the file size of a `32bit` floating point 1-Band GeoTIFF file that currently uses `-99` for `noData` pixels. The relevant part from `gdalinfo -mm`:

```
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=-5.101,3.317
  NoData Value=-99
```

I want to use the `DISCARD_LSB` option to throw away the least significant bits:

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co DISCARD_LSB=16 input.tiff output.tiff
```

But then the `gdalinfo -mm` gives:

```
Band 1 Block=36000x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
    Computed Min/Max=-99.250,3.320
  NoData Value=-99
```

In other words: The original `noData` pixels got treated as normal data in the conversion process (Minimum data value of -99.250).
How can I avoid this?
The same behaviour occurrs when I use `gdalwarp` instead of `gdal_translate`. The version is `2.4.0`.

An uncompressed sample image can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FWEklnueX_QYoKTTzjpsMtFpnreBKqYQ).

Comment: Small sample image would be nice. I suppose that you have written simplified gdal_translate commands instead of what you are really using, is that right? The command, as is stands now, will not really make the file size smaller.

Comment: Oop, you are right, user30184, I oversimplified. I have corrected the gdal_translate expression and added a link to a uncompressed sample image. Thanks.